# Recommended specs for a single-country OSM tile server

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, tile-server

What specs would you recommend for an OSM tile server dedicated to serving tiles for a single, small country (e.g., Portugal only)? Total server load is estimated to be no more than two/three users accessing tiles at the same time.

Comment: If below 5 users you can use a normal windows pc. Though linux would be better http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/

Answer (score 3):

As mapperz pointed out, your load is probably small enough that anything you have will do. If you have some flexibility though, try for fast disks (ideally SSD) and more memory. I suggest fast disks and memory because these are likely to be the limiting factors (for the postgres database instance).

It is interesting to look how openstreetmap does it: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Servers documents their servers. Given their load, it isn't really a lot of machines doing the tiles work...

Answer (score 1):

For users who are looking for such requirement. Here is simple solution to create all openstreetmap tiles for a single country [osm-for-my-country](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/osm-for-my-country). 
There are scripts for all tasks on a Linux machine:

- Install all necessary software like osm2pgsql, postgres, mapnik, kosmtik etc
- Download your country data
- Download and install map style openstreetmap-carto
- Create all tiles for your country
- Update tiles on daily basis
- Serve tiles with node.js or you can serve these offline map tiles with any simple http serevr or apache